# How to use Cursor in Azure Cosmos Mongo Db?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a collection in Azure Cosmos Mongo Db, i'm using a copy activity to read the data and load it into blobs. I'm required to partition the data based on row count, In the copy activity I can see few Cursor Methods which has Limit and Skip, how can I use this to say for example fetch the first 100 records load it into a file, then in the next iteration skip the first 100 and then fetch the next 100 and load it into another file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cursor** methods **limit** and **skip** as per your requirement.

Create variables in the pipeline as shown below:

[image]

Intialize **count** and **rowswritten** variables to `0` with `@int('0')` expression using set variable activities.

Next, use **Until activity** with below dynamic expression.

[image]

Inside Until activity, take copy activity with cosmos mongo db as source and blob as sink.

In the copy activity source, give the `count` variable for the `skip` and set the `limit` to `100`.

Here, I have given the limit as 2:
[image]

Use dataset parameter for the filename and give the below expression for it.

```
File@{variables('count')}.json
```

[image]

Now, use a set variable to increment the `count` variable and store it in `temp` variable. Here, I did by 2 but you need to increment it by `100`.

[image]

Store it back to `count` variable.

[image]

Update the `rowswritten` variable with number of rows read by current copy activity.

```
@activity('Copy data2').output.rowsRead
```

[image]

If this is `0` then our until activity stops and that means source data will be copied like below.
[image]

This is pipeline json for reference:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "count",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@int('0')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "rowsWritten",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@int('0')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Until1",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(variables('rowsWritten'), 0)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data2",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "CosmosDbMongoDbApiSource",
                                    "batchSize": 100,
                                    "cursorMethods": {
                                        "skip": {
                                            "value": "@variables('count')",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "limit": 2
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "JsonSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "JsonWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "CosmosDbMongoDbCollection1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Json1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "FileName": {
                                            "value": "File@{variables('count')}.json",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable3",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@add(variables('count'), 2)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable4",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable3",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "count",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable5",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable4",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "rowsWritten",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Copy data2').output.rowsRead",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "count": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "rowsWritten": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "Integer"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```